# Reading the binding value inside 'init' and 'update'

Tags: knockout.js

When using the [preprocessing](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-preprocessing.html) in a binding I can easily get the value of the binding 'the syntax associated with the binding value before Knockout attempts to parse it'

```
ko.bindingHandlers.uniqueName.preprocess = function(val) {
    return val || 'true';
}
```

How can I get this value in the 'init' or 'update' sections of my custom binding?

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.myBinding = {
  preprocess: function(val) {
    //Here I can read the text value of my binding, i.e., 'myObservale' as text
    console.log(val);
    return val;
  },
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    //How can I read the text value of my binding here? i.e., 'myObservale' as text?
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
      text: valueAccessor()
    });
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {}
};

var vm = {
  myObservable: ko.observable('This is the observable value')
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="myBinding: myObservable"></div>
```

Comment: you can read a current binding value by doing like this in init `ko.unwarp(valueAccessor())` . is this what you looking for or ? sample here http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/s3QTU/542/

Comment: @supercool sorry if I wasn't clear. In your example I want to read 'name'. As stated in the documentation for 'preprocess' if my binding is  myBinding: 1 + 1, the associated value is "1 + 1" as a string. Thanks

Comment: The string you return from the `preprocess()` function is evaluated to get the value to be used in your binding handlers.  Just get the value from the value accessor.

Comment: @JeffMercado, I've updated the question. What I want to read inside the 'init' is precisely the string returned from the preprocess. Not the value of the value accessor. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here but if you want the string `"myObservable"` in your binding, you should pass in a string in your binding.

```
<div data-bind="myBinding: 'myObservable'"></div>
```

If you want to convert the expression passed into your binding to a string, you have to add the quotes to the expression.  Just make sure your binding uses a simple variable name, not a complex expression.

```
<div data-bind="myBinding: myObservable"></div>
ko.bindingHandlers.myBinding = {
    preprocess: function (value) {
        return '"' + value + '"'; // changes the expression to "myObservable"
    },
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor(); // string: 'myObservable'
        // ...
    }
};
```

---

Since you just need the name of the expression to use in another binding, a better thing to do is to use the `preprocess()` function to add additional bindings based on the expression, instead of converting that expression like we are here.

To do so, you need to use the third parameter of the `preprocess()` funciton that exposes a function that can be used to add additional bindings.  With that, you could use the textual expression to derive your attribute bindings.

```
preprocess: function (value, name, addBinding) {
    addBinding('attr', '{ "id": "myprefix_' + value + '" }');
    return value; // use the original expression in your binding
},
```

Your `init()` and `update()` functions could just use the value and not worry about the name.

```
init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = valueAccessor(); // the value of myObservable
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Jeff, I want to add a custom id to my element and want to use the name of the observable for that. Instead of using the "attr: {'id': 'myprefix_' + Id}" binding I want to apply this id binding inside my custom binding to cut out the clutter of the view.

Comment: There's a better way to accomplish that using the `preprocess()` function, without having to change your binding handler to handle the name of the observable. I'll update to show you what could be done.